# Alternative to getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Since the getElementsByTagName() function is new (DOM-1?) I wanted another more reliable method to get a reference to an element based on its tag name/id.

**Edit-**  Without using a framework, since I need to cut down on size; so 10-20K for a framework is unacceptable. I just need the JS code that can fetch an element

Comment: Done properly the 20k or so for jquery is only downloaded once.

Comment: getElementsByTagName() is indeed DOM level 1. It has support going back to IE5, Opera 7, and all versions of Mozilla and Safari. What browser are you worried about? NN3? ;) Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getElementsByTagName

Comment: @Jeremy: seriously, are you by any chance aiming for an older browser(s) that does not have support for getElementsByTagName()?

Comment: There's also getElementById(), but the browsers that support it already support getElementsByTagName().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

getElementsByTagName is not new. It is supported since IE5, FF1 and Opera 7 according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_document.asp)

[edit]
Thanks for pointing this out. It was indeed supported since Opera 7.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That was a really old rumor.

Comment: Its Opera 7, and all versions of Mozilla and Safari -- according to "undefined".

Comment: Actually Opera had it as far back v7. See http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera7/js/dom/

Comment: Don't forget the any bugs: http://ejohn.org/blog/object-getelementsbytagname-ie7-bug/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, getElementsByTagName is not new...

I think you're going to get about 10 references to [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Returns all the paragraph elements:

```
$('p').length
```

If 19kb is too big, and you just want to do element selection, something like [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) works well, at about 4kb. The only thing I would note is that you're probably going to end up needing something that's in jQuery anyway.

http://sizzlejs.com/

Queries are very similar:

```
Sizzle("li");
```

19kb is a really small one-time price to pay for the power of jQuery.

Comment: What about those window[id?] and document[id?] .. would those do?

Comment: I've yet to find a reason *not* to use jquery. It's just so elegant and easy to use...

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that, my answer would be no.

Comment: I need to cut down on size so 10-20K for a framework is unacceptable. I just need the JS code that can fetch an element.

Comment: @Zack: There are, however, plenty of reasons why you might not be able to use jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is select elements, it may be smart to just use the sizzle selector engine and not a full blown library. I would go with the full library, but, going with a selector engine might be useful in limited circumstances.

Sizzle is the CSS selector engine that powers jQuery.

http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Or prototype, etc.  You'll need to use one of these javascript glue libraries to achieve this.  All of them will call this function if it exists, but fake it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation based on the jQuery 1.12.4 implementation. It  uses getElementsByTagName if available. If not, it uses querySelectorAll if available. If not, it falls back on recursively traversal. jQuery 1.12.4 supports older browsers, such as IE6, according to [themselves](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/04/02/browser-support-in-jquery-1-12-and-beyond/).

```
function getElementsByTagName( node, tagName ) {
  if (tagName == '*') {
    tagName = undefined;
  }
  var merge = function( first, second ) {
        var len = +second.length,
            j = 0,
            i = first.length;

        while ( j < len ) {
            first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
        }

        // Support: IE<9
        // Workaround casting of .length to NaN on otherwise arraylike objects (e.g., NodeLists)
        if ( len !== len ) {
            while ( second[ j ] !== undefined ) {
                first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
            }
        }

        first.length = i;

        return first;
    },
    nodeName = function( elem, name ) {
        return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();
    },
  elems, elem,
    i = 0,
  context = node,
  tag = tagName,
    found = typeof context.getElementsByTagName !== "undefined" ?
        context.getElementsByTagName( tag || "*" ) :
        typeof context.querySelectorAll !== "undefined" ?
            context.querySelectorAll( tag || "*" ) :
            undefined;

    if ( !found ) {
        for ( found = [], elems = context.childNodes || context;
            ( elem = elems[ i ] ) != null;
            i++
        ) {
            if ( !tag || nodeName( elem, tag ) ) {
                found.push( elem );
            } else {
                merge( found, getElementsByTagName( elem, tag ) );
            }
        }
    }

  return found;
/*  return tag === undefined || tag && nodeName( context, tag ) ?
        merge( [ context ], found ) :
        found;*/
}
```

I took the getAll() internal function of jQuery 1.12.4 and copied in the two helper functions it needs (jQuery.nodeName and jQuery.merge). I also made sure you can call it with "*" as tagName by adding a few lines in the top of the function. Finally, at the end of the function I commented out some functionality, which adds current node to result (if it matches), and simply returns the found nodes.

Be aware that the function in some cases returns an HTMLCollection, and in other circumstances returns an Array. Also beware that when "*" is passed as tagname, output differs depending on browser: The Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName does not return TextNodes, but the recursive traversal does.

Alternatively, you could use [picoQuery](http://picoQuery.com). picoQuery is an implementation of jQuery, where you can select which methods you need in an online builder. in this case, you need no methods, as selection is part of core, and the build is only 1kb gzipped. picoQuery is written for modern browsers, but falls back to jQuery 1.12.4 for older browsers.