# Repeated IDs in an html document .. how bad an idea is it if they are scoped by a div with a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have an webpage which shows a single item for sale with an add to basket button. The page makes use of alot of javascript to allow the user to customise the item.I now need to modify the page to show multiples of similar items on the same page, each additional item also customisable in the same way  by the user. The javascript makes heavy use of id's in the markup to find elements and manipulate them to provide the client side item customisation.

My 1st thought  is to allow the html markup to repeat for each item,also allowing the IDs to repeat themselves but add an additional div with a unique ID around each items markup to separate the scope of the repeated ID's , making the repeated ID's unique within the containing div. This should allow the javascript to stay relatively the same with the exception that any references to repeated ID's will need to be scoped for a particular DIV ID

Bearing in mind I want the outcome to be cross browser compatible , IE6 -IE9 , Firefox 3+ , Chrome, Safari, Opera, how sensible does this approach sound? Will some browsers disallow repeated IDs or behave badly with them? Any advice as to a better approach or things I should look out for would be very welcomed.
Thanks

-----------------addendum----------------------------------------------------------------

It seems the overwhelming consensus is that it's  a really really bad idea to repeat ID's mostly because the standards  say id's should be unique and although some/most browsers support it now , there's no guarantee for the future. I agree with you all on this totally.

The class approach seemed to be the best route to take from the advice received but now it looks like older browsers won't support it, specifically IE6 and 7. Any advice on a way forwards from here?

-----------------addendum----------------------------------------------------------------

On balance getElementsByTagName seems to be the most compatible way forwards , covering a good spectrum of mobile browsers too.

Thanks for all your advice.

Comment: It's not good practice.  Why don't you just use classes?

Comment: I've not used the approach of using classes before. Not totally sure how it would work but I'll look it up. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There's no "scoping" at all - the "id" value of an element is considered to be a **global** unique identifier. If it's not, then you can depend on various things getting weird.

Comment: I use the word scoping loosly. What I mean is you can get to a non uniquely ID'd dom element by finding it's unique container div element then looking through the children.

Comment: @Pointy I accept your point about things getting weird though, seems although alot of browsers support non unique ids, some don't properly and would be a souce of infinite frustration trying to debug.

Comment: @Rich yes that's basically it. There are so many other ways of tagging content: class values, data attributes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I usually iterate through the `childNodes` or use `getElementsByTagName` with the retrieved element.

```
<div id="div_with_id">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>


<script>

    var div = document.getElementById("div_with_id");
    var cNodes = div.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(var i = 0, l = cNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(cNodes[i].innerHTML);
    }

</script>
```

I use `getElementById` only when necessary, which it turns out, isn't all that often ;)

Remember: `getElementsByTagName` gets all elements of a type, including elements within elements. `childNodes` gets only the top level, but gets everything in the element, including text nodes.

Comment: getElementsByTagName is not supported in older browsers (if that is an issue)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Good catch. It does have a little more support than `getElementsByClassName` according to the link mrtsherman posted. Still...

Comment: @Jeffrey Sweeney I think you're right just googled and found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820369/alternative-to-getelementsbytagname   seems as though getElementsByTagName is better supported than people seem to think.

Comment: yes, really old, but still... I do NOT know about mobile browsers at all here.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss and mobile browsers is something I need to consider. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It seems getElementsByTagName is reasonably compatible across mobile browsers according to this http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/coding%20javascript%20for%20mobile%20browsers%20%28part%208%29%20-%20dom.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Don't reuse id's. Ever. It results in very unexpected behavior. If you need to reuse markers then make use of classes instead.

If you have the following syntax

```
<div id="container1"><span id="a"></span></div>
<div id="container2"><span id="a"></span></div>
```

What would you expect `document.getElementById('a')` to do?

Instead use:

```
<div id="container1"><span class="a"></span></div>
<div id="container2"><span class="a"></span></div>
```

Then you can access them via.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a')
```

Comment: This is really all there is to it.

Comment: I understand getElementById won't work directly but you can find the containing div's ID and then look at the child elements id's which are unique within the div.

Comment: I agree, all id's should be unique, the html specifications say so! But I do think you can do something like this: `var c2 = document.getElementById('container2'); var c2a = c2.getElementById('a');`

Comment: @RustyJeans I tested that earlier. No go on Safari.

Comment: @Rich - I've read through thousands of SO posts and have seen more than my fair share of questions inquiring why things don't work. Many are caused by duplicate id's. Classes are built to handle this use case, the browser developers have coded their pages and methods with the expectation that they are unique, it's required for W3C compliant pages, and other developer's expectations are that it will be unique. This is one convention I would not deviate from. I'm not just being 'this is the way it is, so just do it that way.' I really think it is a phenomenally bad idea.

Comment: @mrtsherman speaking of standards, `getElementsByClassName` is a fairly new one at the moment. I wouldn't advise using it for a little while longer.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney - thanks, made me lookup the compatibility table. They have a nice note that IE6/7 always returns the first element id regardless of its location in the DOM. In addition, ie6/7 don't have `getElementsByClassName` support as you pointed out. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods

Comment: @mrtsherman Thanks for the addendum. That made alot of sense as to how to use classes instead of repeated ID's. It's kind of obvious now it's been mentioned.

Comment: Any alternatives to getElementsByClassName that will work on older IE browsers?

Comment: @Rich `getElementsByTagName` and `childNodes`?

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with HTML 4.01 specification dated Dec 24, 1999 it is invalid if the id attribute has a duplicate value.

You shoud use class, both referenced here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 2):

The DOM is not the supplied text.  The ID is supposed to be unique in the DOM.  If a browser allows more than one node with the same ID, there's no guarantee that it will do so in the future.  So even if it works, you shouldn't take advantage of that fact.  Just do the right thing and either use a unique ID, or a class as appropriate.