# Creating multiple fields in the same line

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a dynamic form, where, if the user click on the plus icon, it should create two new fields in the same line.

The code that I have right now, it only create one single field, I tried to duplicate the same code in the funtion, but it only create two fields in vertical position and not in the same line.

Thank you Kindly !

Javascript code

```
var survey_options = document.getElementById('columna');
var add_more_fields = document.getElementById('add_more_fields');
var remove_fields = document.getElementById('remove_fields');

function Añadir(){
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('class','form-control');
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder','Another Field');
    survey_options.appendChild(newField);
}

function Eliminar(){
    var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(input_tags.length > 2) {
        survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1]);
    }
}
```

Html Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Awsome Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- My Title-->
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
      
      <form class="Form" id="formulario">
          <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
          <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

          <!-- Campos en Columnas-->
        <div class="container" id="contenedor">
            <div class="row" id="campo">

                <div class="col" id="columna">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Infraestructura">
                </div>
  
                <div class="col" id="columna">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Infraestructura">
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
        
          <!-- Iconos de Agregar / Eliminar Campos-->
          <div class="Controls">
              <a href="#" id="add_more_fields" onclick="Añadir()"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Añadir</a>
              <a href="#" id="removefields" onclick="Eliminar()"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>Eliminar</a>
          </div>
          
      </form>
          <!-- JS Script-->    
          <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Very first point `id` value must not repeat. It should be unique. [For More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233191/repeated-ids-in-an-html-document-how-bad-an-idea-is-it-if-they-are-scoped-by)
- In html, `input`s are embedded in `div` so you should follow the same in JS to get same result.
- `div.col-lg-6` makes tags inside them to set half of screen when screen size is large. It will helps to your design
- As I said, I created `div.col-lg-6.mb-2` in JS and embedded `input` in `div` to get final result. `mb-2` gives `margin-bottom`
- `div` is embedded in `div#campo` and final result is here

```js
var survey_options = document.getElementById('campo');
var add_more_fields = document.getElementById('add_more_fields');
var remove_fields = document.getElementById('remove_fields');

function Añadir(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-6 mb-2')
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('class','form-control');
    newField.setAttribute('placeholder','Another Field');
    survey_options.appendChild(newDiv)
    newDiv.appendChild(newField);
}

function Eliminar(){
    var input_tags = survey_options.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(input_tags.length > 2) {
        survey_options.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1]);
    }
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Awsome Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <body>
      
      <form class="Form" id="formulario">
          <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
          <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

          <!-- Campos en Columnas-->
        <div class="container" id="contenedor">
            <div class="row" id="campo">

                <div class="col-lg-6 mb-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Infraestructura">
                </div>
  
                <div class="col-lg-6 mb-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Infraestructura">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
          <!-- Iconos de Agregar / Eliminar Campos-->
          <div class="Controls">
              <a href="#" id="add_more_fields" onclick="Añadir()"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Añadir</a>
              <a href="#" id="removefields" onclick="Eliminar()"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>Eliminar</a>
          </div>
          
      </form>
  </body>
```

---

**Update**

```
<!-- In HTML -->
  <a href="#" id="add_more_fields" onclick="createTwoInput()"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Añadir</a>
<!-- In Script -->
  function createTwoInput(){
      Añadir();
      Añadir();
  }
```

If any clarification needed, Mention in comment

Comment: Perfect ! Though, if I would like that the add button create the two fields at once, how could I do it ? Write " var newField = document.createElement('input'); " twice ?

Sorry if this sound not so logic, I'm very new in javascript ( well I started yestarday :') )

Comment: create another `function` and in that function call `Añadir()` twice. I will update the answer